# SQL: Automatically copy records from one database to another database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I am trying to find out an ideal way to automatically copy new records from one database to another. the databases have different structure! I achieved it by writing VBS scripts which copy the data from one to another and triggered the scripts from another application which passes arguments to the script. But I faced issues at points where there were more than 100 triggers. i.e. 100wscript processes trying to access the database and they couldn't complete the task.

I want to find out a simpler solution inside SQL, I read about setting triggers, Stored procedure and running them from SQL agent, replication etc. The requirement is that I have to copy records to another database periodically or when there is a new record into another database.

Which method will suit me the best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [CDC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895315.aspx) to do this activity. Create a SSIS package using CDC and run that package periodically through SQL Server Agent Job. CDC will store all the changes of that table and will do all those changes to the destination table when you run the package. Please follow the below link.
http://sqlmag.com/sql-server-integration-services/combining-cdc-and-ssis-incremental-data-loads

Answer (score 0):

The word periodically in your question suggests that you should go for Jobs. You can schedule jobs in SQL Server using Sql Server agent and assign a period. The job will run your script as per assigned frequency.

Comment: Could I also use Stored procedures instead of scripts? Because I have 8 different scripts, if periodically run the ideal time for my situation would be every minute.

Comment: Yes, you can put your scripts in stored procedures and the job will run the stored procedure in the time interval that you define.

Answer (score 0):

PrabirS: Change Data Capture
This is a good option. Because it uses the truncation-log to create something similar to the Command Query Segregation Pattern (CQRS).

Alok Gupta: A SQL Job that runs in the SQL Agent
This too is a good option, given that you have something like a modified date thus you can filter the altered data. You can create a Stored Procedure and let it run regularly in the SQL Agent.

A third option could be triggers (the change will happen in the same transaction). 
This option is useful for auditing and logging. But you should definitely avoid writing business logic in triggers, as triggers are more or less hidden and occur without directly calling them (similar to CDC actually). I have actually created a trigger about half a year ago that captured the data and inserted it somewhere else in xml-format as the columns in the original table could change over time (multiple projects using the same database(s)).

-Edit-
By the way, your question more or less suggest a lack of a clear design pattern and that the used technique is not the main problem. You could try to read how an ETL-layer is build, or try to implement a "separations of concerns". Note; it is hard to tell if this is the case, but given how you formulated your question, an unclear design is something that pops up in my mind as possible problem.